# Web application buttons are not clickable in Internet Explorer while in Firefox and Chrome they work properly

Tags: internet-explorer-11, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using a .NET web application and for some of its features Internet Explorer is needed. Internet Explorer 11 is installed on Windows Server Standard 2012 R2. 
The issue is that the buttons on the web application are not clickable while on Firefox and Chrome they work properly with a color change hover effect.

The issue is not related to the application as the buttons work on an IE 11 installed on Windows 10.

I tried already these so far:

- IE Compatibility view
- Website included in Local intranet and Trusted sites (disabling Protected Mode)
- In the browser Advanced Settings I tried these options:

  - Enable third-party browser extensions
  - Enable visual styles on buttons and controls in webpages
  - Play animations in webpages
- Browser reset

In Firefox I disabled Shockwave Flash and Java plugins and the buttons still work properly.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unfortunately, the application is an off-the-shelf one and we do not have the source code.

Comment: Try to open the application in the IE browser, then press the F12 button to open the F12 developer tools, in the Console tab, refresh the page to check whether it contains any JavaScript error, perhaps the application are using some JQuery plugins and they are not supported in the IE browser. If that is the case, you might   have to contact with the developer.

Comment: But as I mentioned in the question above, it works fine on IE 11 on Windows 10.

Comment: It's my mistake, you still could use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some JavaScript error. Besides, I suggest you could check [this article](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/internet-explorer) and verify whether the IE 11 (on the windows server) enable JavaScript.

Comment: Well done @ZhiLv-MSFT! It worked. It was JavaScript-related issue. Thank you!